# Corrupted Data after replacing disk in Windows 10 Storage Space

Tags: windows-10, video-conversion, hard-drive-recovery, file-corruption, storage-spaces

I have a Windows 10 upgraded Storage Pool with 5 drives (Parity, thinly provisioned).  'Upgraded' means that this Storage Space supports rebalancing/optimizing (and this was a Windows 8 machine before).  I have a total of 5 drives in the pool:  3x4TB, 1x5TB, 1x2TB.  I recently had a 3TB drive fail, so I replaced it with the 5TB drive.  That 3TB drive was shown as "disconnected", but all files were fully intact and I had no problems reading/writing to the Storage Space... it just told me that I had "reduced resiliency".  I took out the 3TB drive and replaced it with the 5TB drive, and after the "optimization" process with this new drive, a large percentage of files are now seen as corrupt.  I can view all files in their old directory structure, but when I try playing them (they are mainly video files), many of them will give me a corruption error in my media player.  I believe that since all files are properly seen in File Explorer, and they seem to be taking up the same amount of space, that this looks like a Storage Space metadata problem.  Many of the files play just fine, however.  I have tried running "chkdsk /r" a couple of times, but this runs for many hours and comes back with 0 problems and does not fix anything.

Is there any way to repair the Storage Space metadata?  I've looked into software called ReclaiMe, but this only seems to work up to Windows 8 Storage Spaces.

Alternatively, is there a way to repair all video files at once?  There are a combination of .avi, .mpg, .mp4, and .mkv video files on this Storage Space, so it would be nice if I could just say "Repair all" and everything worked again.

Any help appreciated... even insight as to how this could have happened.  Thanks!

Comment: If some of the files appear to be corrupt but many are not corrupt it actually does sound like those files are actually corrupt.  Have you tried `ReclaiMe` since there wasn't really any changes to Storage Spaces with the release of Windows 10

Comment: I tried running ReclaiMe, but it does not even recognize any Storage Space on my computer.  I believe because this is the 'upgraded' Storage Space that has the Optimization (rebalancing) feature in Windows 10.  What's baffling to me is how a redundancy mechanism somehow caused all of this data corruption... before I took out the failed 3TB drive, everything was functioning normally.  Only after putting in a fresh drive did problems appear.